# SyntaxError in function argument

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Try to install a package and get SyntaxError with python 2. What does the : in the function argument mean or how does it work?

```
def line(self, from_: P, to: P, paint=None, character=None):
```

I guess it is python 3 thing and I can neither name nor find it.

Comment: It's called "function annotations" - it's a 3.x only thing.

Comment: @JonClements Super awesome, thanks.